# Flutter: Animate Conditional Items Added to Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a stateless widget in Flutter that responds to changes to a property in a Provider model. When I click on an "edit" button, I toggle a boolean in my model and my reminders go into edit mode like this:

[image: reminders]

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //A boolean from my model
  var editMode = Provider.of<ModelDashboard>(context).sidebarEditMode;

  return Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(editMode ? 5 : 15, 15, editMode ? 5 : 15, 12),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            if (editMode) ...[
              PPReorder(
                index: index,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 5),
            ],
            //Rest of row...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]
  );
}
```

So as `editMode` changes, it adjusts some padding and shows/hides a couple elements in my row.

I looked at some of the animation options and they don't seem right to me:

- `AnimatedContainer` - I tried animating the `width` to `0` and I got overflow errors.
- `AnimatedOpacity` - The item still takes up space when its `opacity` is `0`.
- `AnimatedPositioned` - My items are not positioned within a `Stack`.

What would be the appropriate way to animate the appearance of these conditional items in my `Row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use [AnimatedCrossFade](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html).
I had almost same situation where I need to show and hide one element with animation and `AnimatedCrossFade` is easiest and best way to implement animation.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //A boolean from my model
  var editMode = Provider.of<ModelDashboard>(context).sidebarEditMode;

  return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(editMode ? 5 : 15, 15, editMode ? 5 : 15, 12),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              AnimatedCrossFade(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                firstChild: Row(
                  children: [
                    PPReorder(
                      index: index,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  ],
                ),
                secondChild: Container(),
                crossFadeState: editMode
                    ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                    : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
              )
              //Rest of row...
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]
  );
}
```

You can play around with this as per your requirments.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. Doing this was a lot easier than I thought it would be, and I didn't even have to change my widget to be Stateful. Nice! Thank you very much!